# SQL lambda output not correct using nested select

Tags: sql, lambda, nested-select

I have 2 tables, `Terms` and `Site_Program_Term`:

- `Terms` columns: Id, SiteId, Name, IsHoliday, DateStart, DateEnd, Year, IsActive
- `Site_Program_Term` columns: Id, ProgName, SiteId, TermId, Year

Using the above 2 tables, I need to display output with primarily below columns

```
Name, StartDate, EndDate, NumberOfPrograms
```

I am getting the desired output but the 'NumberOfPrograms' is not showing the correct values. It should give me a count of all the Programs for a set of particular Term, Year and Site.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the base code.

```
var terms = db.Terms.Where(t => t.SiteId == id && t.IsActive).ToList().Select(t => new
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                SiteId = t.SiteId,
                Name = t.Name,
                IsHoliday = t.IsHoliday,
                DateStart = t.DateStart,
                DateEnd = t.DateEnd,
                Year = t.Year,

                PubProgram = ( 
                    db.Site_Program_Term
                    .Where (spt => spt.SiteId == id && spt.Year == t.Year)
                    .Select(s => s).Count()
                ),
            }).OrderBy(n => n.DateStart).ToList();
```

Comment: What language and/or framework is this in? It certainly isn't plain SQL...

Comment: I am using lambda expressions in C#

Answer (score 0):

> It should give me a count of all the
>   Programs for a set of particular **Term**, Year and Site.

But your `Where` condition only includes `Year` and `Site`, but not the `Term`. So

```
.Where(spt => spt.SiteId == id && spt.Year == t.Year)
```

should actually be:

```
.Where(spt => spt.SiteId == id && spt.Year == t.Year && spt.TermId == t.Id)
```

Note that if you are by any chance using Entity Framework (Core) and you have properly configured navigation property on the `Term` class such as

```
public class Term
{
    // ...
    public List<Site_Program_Term> SiteProgramTerms { get; set; }
}
```

then you can rewrite your query as

```
var terms = db.Terms
    .Where(t => t.SiteId == id && t.IsActive)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        SiteId = t.SiteId,
        Name = t.Name,
        IsHoliday = t.IsHoliday,
        DateStart = t.DateStart,
        DateEnd = t.DateEnd,
        Year = t.Year,

        PubProgram = t.SiteProgramTerms.Where(spt => spt.SiteId == id && spt.Year == t.Year).Count()
    })
    .OrderBy(n => n.DateStart)
    .ToList();
```

Note that this time you don't need to include `spt.TermId == t.Id` condition, because  `SiteProgramTerms` property contains only site program terms with `TermId` that matches the `Id` of the `Term`. Also note that the first `.ToList()` should be omitted, because it causes query to be sent to the SQL server as multiple `SELECT` queries (as opposed to just one `SELECT` when `.ToList()` is not present).